# Applescript Select File Whose Name Contains Any Part of a List of Values or Text

Tags: file, select, applescript

I need to select a bunch of files with different names from a folder. This is the script I've got to work on a small scale so far.

```
tell application "Finder" to select (every file of target of front window whose 
name contains "3123" or name contains "3125" or name contains 3166)
```

But I need a script that will work on a large scale where I can just enter myValues something similar to

```
set myValues to {3101, 3102, 3103, 3456, 6789, etc. etc.}
tell application "Finder" to select (every file of target of front window whose 
name contains myValues)
```

But when I use that script it won't select any files when I have more than one number set to myValues. Also if you could show me how to change it to work with text as well that would be awesome.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set myValues to {"3101", "3102", "3103", "3456", "6789"}

tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of target of front window

set matchedFiles to {}
repeat with aFile in my fileList
    repeat with aValue in myValues
        tell application "System Events" to if aFile's name contains (contents of aValue) then set end of matchedFiles to (aFile as text)
    end repeat
end repeat

tell application "Finder" to select matchedFiles
```

EDIT - added Finder window and regulus6633's suggestion:

```
set myValues to {"3101", "3102", "3103", "3456", "6789"}

tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of target of front Finder window as alias list

set matchedFiles to {}
repeat with aFile in my fileList
    repeat with aValue in myValues
        tell application "System Events" to if aFile's name contains (contents of aValue) then set end of matchedFiles to (aFile as text)
    end repeat
end repeat

tell application "Finder" to select matchedFiles
```

EDIT 2

```
set myValues to {"3125", "3123"}

tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of target of front Finder window as alias list
set matchedFiles to {}
repeat with aFile in my fileList
    repeat with aValue in myValues
        tell application "System Events" to if aFile's name contains (contents of aValue) then set end of matchedFiles to (aFile as text)
    end repeat
end repeat

if matchedFiles ≠ {} then
    tell application "Finder"
        select matchedFiles -- you don't need to select files to duplicate them
        duplicate matchedFiles to (choose folder)
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: Without any testing, my question would be if system events can handle a Finder file specifier. If so then no problem otherwise you could append "as alias list" to the end of the first Finder command. Off hand I think it would be a problem but I'm not certain.

Comment: It seems to be working for me but you are right, you can create an alias list on top to avoid any Finder / System Events reference problems.

Comment: Works like a champ! Y'all are awesome. I have Apple Training Series: Applescript 1-2-3 arriving today. So hopefully I'll be able to answer my future questions from it. Thanks again!

Comment: So I was trying to pass those selected files into an action in Automator but that hasn't worked out as planned. I done some reading in the Applescript 1-2-3 book trying to duplicate those selected files to a new folder of my choosing. But I just can't get it to work out after trying a million different combinations.

Comment: Here is my script    <!-- language: lang-js -->    set myValues to {"3125", "3123"}

tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of target of front Finder window as alias list

set matchedFiles to {}
repeat with aFile in my fileList
 repeat with aValue in myValues
  tell application "System Events" to if aFile's name contains (contents of aValue) then set end of matchedFiles to (aFile as text)
 end repeat
end repeat

tell application "Finder" to select matchedFiles
duplicate matchedFiles to choose folder

Comment: Here is my error.  "Can’t make {\"Macintosh HD:Users:PhilosophizerMD:Desktop:Afni_Files 2:3123_FA.nii\", \"Macintosh HD:Users:PhilosophizerMD:Desktop:Afni_Files 2:3125_FA.nii\"} into type reference." number -1700 from {"Macintosh HD:Users:PhilosophizerMD:Desktop:Afni_Files 2:3123_FA.nii", "Macintosh HD:Users:PhilosophizerMD:Desktop:Afni_Files 2:3125_FA.nii"} to reference

Comment: Thanks for the help! What's the easiest way to duplicate files without selecting them? Oh, and could you explain what the error means so I know what to focus on next time to fix it. Thanks for everything!

Comment: simply remove the select matchedFiles line in my last edit. You are getting an error because the duplicate command is not in a tell app Finder block.